# ASP.NET AD login and switch User

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I've created an Intranet website which uses AD to identify the users

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

But I also need a way to enable an administrator to login to a administrator account in the browser where a normal AD user is logged in on the windows machine. Some way of logout the current AD user in the browser and login on the administrator AD account.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use Forms authentication to allow an administrator to login.  But IIS does not allow both Forms and Windows authentication to be enabled at the same time.

One possible solution is to switch to Forms authentication and use the OWIN Identity security system.  When a user is not authenticated and is not an administrator, auto login/register the user.  To do that, override the CheckPasswordAsync() method of the OWIN UserManager class. Then you can have an Administrator login page because your CheckPasswordAsync() method will not auto login if the current user is an administrator.